# Do the Dragonlance Gods really want balance?

Tags: dragonlance

The Cataclysm was sent by the gods because the Kingpriest of Istar demanded the power of a god to destroy evil. Because of his arrogance and ignorance of the need for balance its posited that all the gods did this. So why does Takhisis keep trying to rule the world? Wouldn't that throw the balance out of whack again?

Comment: Fish gotta swim, birds gotta fly, evil gods gotta try to take over the world.

Comment: I believe there was a story where Takhisis was working with good gods against god of evil magic, who was threatening to take over/destroy the balance. But then she was trying to do it on multiple occasions as well with other gods unifying against her.

Comment: In the first trilogy, I think Takhisis wanted her followers to rule the world. It isn't until she steals Krynn and tries to pose as the one true god that she is messing with the balance. After all, Paladine was there to balance her.

Comment: It's the gods' task and destiny to struggle for balance, and they fundamentally are in balance. This includes them following their own goals in their own ways - it balances out. Mortals trying to mess with godly powers are what threatens this balance.

Answer (score 2):

The gods of Krynn want order, not balance. Each has their own idea for how to accomplish this. For example, Takhisis believes in order through subjugating the world. Paladine, the major god of good, tries to bring about order through educating the people. Gilean, the major god of neutrality wants order by allowing mortals to be able to choose their own path. The Balance of Krynn is formed by the gods of these three alignments (Good, Evil, and Neutrality) *(Dragonlance Campaign Setting, ch. 4)*.

If Takhisis destroys the gods of magic the balance would be destroyed, however she would control all of Krynn. The likely outcome would be the release of Chaos from the Greygem of Gargath, which happened anyway to dawn The Age of Mortals [after the Chaos War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/534415.Dragons_of_Summer_Flame).

The gods together brought the Cataclysm because Istar was arrogantly rampaging over everyone, not just evil. In *Divine Hammer* he even tried to kill all the Wizards of High Sorcery. They ganged up on him because he was a menace to everyone.

Comment: Just to expand a little bit, I believe the Kingpriest went so far as to attack other good-aligned temples/churches and even those that he just didn't see eye-to-eye with. As Vogon Poet said, the Kingpriest wasn't just eliminating evil, he was trying to eliminate everyone that didn't have the same exact mindset. He was obviously nuts but it didn't help that someone in his court was a traitor of sorts and convinced him that the plagues the gods released as a warning were simply a last desperate ploy by the evil forces to scare him.

Comment: @goat_fab Paladine himself told the heroes of the lance that good if there is no evil to balance it out.....becomes worse than evil.  And that in the same way as the kingpriest did.......the kingpriest was called GOOD by Paladin! thus the lesson he taught the hoeroes was...without balance even what is called good can go down darker pathes than Thakisis!